# three.js how to stop render when the user can't see the 3d space?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a simple globe render that spins. So far so good, but I'd like to basically *pause* the render when the user is no longer looking at the dom element that the renderer is a child of, as the element is a ways down on the page and valuable resources are being used where they don't have to be. Here's what I have so far—

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;

    //element is almost about to be visible, time to start rendering
    if (scrollPosition >= topOfElement - 200) {
        if (everythingIsLoaded && !isRendering) {
            render();
            console.log('render has been started');
        } else {
            //wait until everythingIsLoaded is true
        }
    //element is not visible, stop rendering
    } else {
        //need to stop rendering here!
        //this doesn't work, dunno how to do this
        if (animationFrame) {
            stopRendering(render);
            console.log('render has been halted');
        }
    }
});
```

and my `render()` function looks like this—

```
const render = () => {
    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame( render );
    sphere.rotation.y += 0.001;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    isRendering = true;
};
```

Is there a way to **stop** the render when the user is no longer able to see the webGL render region?

I tried to do something like this (as you can see in the above code)—

```
var stopRendering = (af) => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(af);
    isRendering = false;
};
```

but that doesn't seem to actually stop the render at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) accepts the id returned by [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which in your case is the variable named `animationFrame`. It's the same as setTimeout and clearTimeout.

Right now you're passing it an entire function reference, the `render()` function. It's hard to track your use of global variables in the code provided, but you probably just want to do:

```
if (animationFrame) {
    stopRendering(animationFrame);
}
```

Since in your case you're assigning the id returned by `requestAnimationFrame` to the variable `animationFrame`.

Comment: Aah, I didn't realise it took the animationFrame ID. this worked perfectly! thank you! :-)